# jquery "vertical accordion" with "autoplay" and mouseover play

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, accordion

I am searching for Jquery vertical accordion with auto play and along with mouse over play. but i did not get any solution till. can you please please give me a reference link for that.

Comment: Did you ever find a good one? I've been looking as well. I've posted a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287541/vertical-accordion-content-slider-ideally-jquery One person suggested building my own, which is a bit tricky. And the one I did find works ok, but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain about the autoplay options, but [jQuery's UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) is the best accordion solution I've seen. Also, if you include this framework you'll get lots of widgets for your app. Really worth looking.

Hope I can help!

Comment: i am searching for auto play Vertical Accordion past 1 month. i need that can you give me any demo or reference link.

Comment: There is a link in the answer, to the demo page http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: ya i have checked it but that is not much suitable. i want the same thing with auto play, there is a mouse over but no auto play

Comment: Sounds like you need a slider and not an accordion

Comment: ya like that, vertical Accordion with slider. Which you have sent is good, with in that i need auto play, please don't hesitate help me