# Vertical Accordion Content Slider ideally jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider, accordion

I've been searching for a while for a vertical accordion content slider.  I've found one: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion, and it's pretty good.  I implemented it on my site http://www.pixeltrics.com/

But there are a couple of things I'm not happy with.  It's not very smooth, and even though I set the autodelay time to 4 seconds, it seems the first slide takes a lot longer to switch to the second and then they start switching like every second.  So something isn't quite right.

Does anyone know of another vertical accordion plug-in I can try?  Ideally a jQuery one.

Thanks.

Comment: It operates smoothly for me in Chrome. Have you tried it on other browsers and computer configurations? In your case, I would also suggest adding fixed heights so it doesn't "pop" them after the animation is finished to expand to fit content; though if you set fixed heights you'll need to adjust when the content changes--or if that's not practical, then set the heights in JavaScript after page load.

Comment: Yes, the first animation does have a longer delay longer than all subsequent animations. But it's not a problem with your usage or configuration; I suggest reporting that bug to the plugin author.

Answer (score 4):

Why use a plugin when it's easy enough with jQuery alone? Example...

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('.body').hide();              

    $('.heading').hover(function() {

        $(this).next('.body').stop().slideToggle(500);
        $(this).parent().siblings('.wrap').children('.body').stop().slideUp(500);

    }, function() {

        $(this).next('.body').stop().slideToggle(500);

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I also need it to auto-play/slide every 4 seconds, and to start out with a set slide.  And I'd like it to pause if someone mouse-overs but then resume a few seconds later.  So it's kinda like a combination of an accordion and a slider

Answer (score 1):

There is JQuery UI which is almost the brother of JQuery and it has a lot of useful widgets including an accordion:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

There's a really cool image and accordion jQuery plugin I developed called Slidorion. it combines an image slider and an accordion so might be what your looking for. Check it out...

http://www.slidorion.com